# Can I access web.config in extension method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can I access values in application settings of web.config in extension method?

I have the below code but it is not working:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function DocCountExt(ByVal value As Collection) As Integer
    Dim maxOffSet As Integer = Integer.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(APP_SETTINGS_OFFSET))
    return maxOffSet
End Function
```

The above code does not work.

Comment: The ConfigurationManager.AppSettings returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blasted minimum thirty characters got me again :/

Original answer:

```
Yes
```

Comment: Can you provide a lot more info - what isn't working? Is it throwing an exception, or producing an unexpected result?

Comment: It is working now, I spelled incorectly the key in the wbe.config. :) My BAD

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`

Answer (score 0):

Yes very much you can. Pass it as a parameter because Exension Method is static.